# return type of method with nested promises

Tags: angularjs, typescript, resharper

I am getting error from resharper

> Cannot convert type 'IPromise < IPromise < void > >' to type
>   'IPromise < void >': Types of property 'then' of types 'IPromise < void >'
>   and 'IPromise < IPromise < void > >' are incompatible

but if I compile the project using `tsc` from command line I am not getting any error. As I understand the nested promises are being handled by angular and the calling method does not have to check for nested `then`

example code

```
private somemethod(): ng.IPromise<void> {
        return this.promiseOuter().then(this.promiseInner);
}

private promiseOuter = (): ng.IPromise<void> => { }

private promiseInner = (): ng.IPromise<void> => { }
```

so what really is return type: is it `promise< void>` or `promise< promise <void>>`

Comment: I'm guessing there's a problem with the type inference done by resharper. Maybe complain to them about that? :)